# Erratic file naming of *.dacpac files when building a *.sqlproj SSDT project on a TeamCity 7 build server

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, sql-server-data-tools

We have an MSBuild task that builds our *.sqlproj file, the output of which is loaded back into TeamCity as an artifact for subsequent deployment.

Similar to this user, we are having some unpredictable output file naming happen:
[Invalid file names when trying to deploy SSDT project with TeamCity 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857927/invalid-file-names-when-trying-to-deploy-ssdt-project-with-teamcity-8)

It appears that sometimes, it produces this output file under /bin/Release:

```
MyProj.sqlproj.dacpac
```

Then subsequent builds produce this file in the same folder:

```
MyProj.dacpac
```

We haven't done indepth testing yet - I was wondering if anyone else has seen similar or has a suggested troubleshooting path?

To be clear, it's the same task, running the same command against the same project - just run repeatedly overtime as new checkins happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after looking more closely at the build log I could see that the TeamCity MSBuild runner appears to be creating some temporary virtual project files (or something, I don't know for sure because they get deleted) with names like:

```
MyProj.sqlproj.teamcity
```

I theorized that this may be confusing MSBuild or one of the targets related to building dacpacs, so I replaced the TeamCity MSBuild build step with a Command Line build step that calls MSBuild on the original project file itself, and this appeared to solve the problem. It now produces the dacpac with the file I'm expecting.

I don't have time to dig further now, but I could believe that there's some logic in the chain somewhere that is deriving the name for the final *.dacpac from the name of the project file being used. My guess is that it just strips off everything after the last "." and attaches the ".dacpac" suffix.

I don't fully know why it would occasionally create a *.dacpac file with the *correct* name, but I was at times doing a manual build in the TeamCity agent work folder from the commandline on the build server itself, so this may have just been a file leftover from previous executions.

Comment: Are different build agents running different versions of MsBuild.  I've seen differences between v15 and v16.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have conflicting .sqlproj files being checked in.

I'd start by checking the history.

Comment: I suspected that myself, and checked the history of changes to the .sqlproj file. There were plenty of legitimate changes (e.g. adding new objects to the project) but nothing that would appear to control the name of the final *.dacpac.